# Displaying wordpress Recent Posts on a .Net site?

Tags: .net, wordpress

I need to display the titles (and perhaps the first line) of  some blog 'recent posts' from a Wordpress php site on another website that runs on .Net.

after doing a little googling I haven't found any definative resources. some have mentioned using RSS.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please.

Cheers!

Comment: Grabbing the RSS feed is the way to go. Every WP blog has one (look into the source code of a WP page), and .NET has tools to parse it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's pretty easy using the [SyndicationFeed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed.aspx) class:

```
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create("http://someblog.wordpress.com/feed/"))
{
    var feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);
    // Print title and summary of 5 most recent posts
    foreach (var post in feed.Items.Take(5))
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("--- {0} ---", post.Title.Text);
        Console.WriteLine (post.Summary.Text);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```